# Could someone have made changes in the SQL database schema without being tracked (SQL Server 2008 with SQL Server Management Studio)?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, database-schema, ssms

I'm using the Entity Framework 6 to manage the access to our database, and I have now been told that some data is missing in the way I'm displaying it. It was said that the respective column(s) has always been in the database and that I or the EF must have failed to load it somehow.

But I am/was pretty sure (though not 100%) that this column hasn't been there before and got included some days ago. Since the database was created months ago I have regularly updated stuff in there and always reloaded the EF to stay up-to-date with the changes to the database, and this one was never proposed.

I checked the report on ALTER/DROP usings but I can't see any change in recent times. Does that mean I'm wrong and supposedly the Entity Framework has failed to see that on table has one more column, or could someone have made a change without being noticed? If that could have been the case: are there other ways I could try and track down that change or just see if there has been one?

Comment: Any chance you have an old DB backup to check if the column was present?